# Shared scope of a directive when 'controller as' syntax is used

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

Here is a simple example of using directives (adapted from the official guide)
- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnjasim/v9czLk0t/)

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer></my-customer>
</div>


angular.module('my-module', [])
.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
     $scope.vojta = { name: 'Vojta', address: '3456 Somewhere Else' };
 })
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'Name: {{vojta.name}} Address: {{vojta.address}}'
     }
 });
```

The above directive has the same scope as its parent controller. How can I do the same with **controller as** syntax?

It's possible to do this with isolated scopes, but I am looking for a solution where you don't create a separate scope for the directive. Is it simply possible?

I tried everything from *controllerAs*, *bindToController* and *require: '^ngController'* without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `controllerAs` syntax, in your controller create a ViewModel object having the reference to `this` as follows:

```
var vm = this;
vm.vojta = { name: 'Vojta', address: '3456 Somewhere Else' }; //your object
```

And in the template, you have to use the `as` to give an alias to your controller as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl"> //now inside this scope use 'ctrl' which acts as the 'scope' of the controller.
  <my-customer></my-customer>
</div>
```

In your directive:

```
template: 'Name: {{ctrl.vojta.name}} Address: {{ctrl.vojta.address}}' //notice the use of 'ctrl'
```

Working fiddle [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/mth6gkw8/)

Comment: `var self = this;   self.vojta = { name: 'Vojta', address: '3456 Somewhere Else' };`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The variable ctrl you define in the view is accessible in the template? That's the point I missed.

Comment: yes, it is available everywhere inside the div where you have defined the controller unless there is an isolate scope directive.

Comment: Hi, What if I have different/multiple "Controller as syntax"? 

Controller as ctrl
Controller2 as ctrl2

and my Directive is the same (One Directive)

 ?

Comment: umm, not really sure about that.